# Change values of the pointer of slice in Golang

Tags: go, slice

Have a slice with float64 values. And I want to multiply them without new memory allocation. Is it possible?

```
multiple(&slice)


func multiple(slice *[]float64) {

    for index, value := range *slice {
        ??? =  value * 100
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work:

```
func multiple(slice *[]float64) {

    for index, value := range *slice {
        (*slice)[index] =  value * 100
    }
}
```

You are passing a pointer to a slice. Are you sure that's what you need? The following would also work:

```
func multiple(slice []float64) {

    for index, value := range slice {
        slice[index] =  value * 100
    }
}
```

When you pass `*[]float64`, the function gets a pointer to the slice. To work with the elements of the slice, the function has to dereference the pointer, then dereference the array pointed to by the slice.

When you pass `[]float64`, the function gets a slice, which contains a pointer to the underlying array, length, and capacity.

Comment: bserdar As I understand, if I'm passing without pointer ```multiple(slice []float64)```, there will happen a new memory allocation, as a copy of my array. Am I right?

Comment: A slice contains a reference to an array. If you pass it without a pointer, that reference will be copied, not the array itself.

Comment: Almost. The parenthesis around slice (`(*slice)[index]`) are incorrect. ;) As per allocs and alike: https://gist.github.com/mwmahlberg/dafcdaf890e9252058b4a36e9fca6b97

Comment: @flybox Run the above code as a benchmark. **BOTH** turn out to have 0 allocations in the code under test.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg why incorrect? https://play.golang.org/p/wudCvHuTQNS

Comment: @bserdar My bad. I was working with a `[]*float64`, as you can see... Made more sense to me, I guess ;)

Comment: @bserdar What is the difference then between ```slice []float64``` and ```slice *[]float64``` when passing as an argument?